# JavaScript control for drilling down into stats tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, statistics, treemap

I have a JSON data tree with statistical information:

```
{
  prefix: "a",
  count: 20,
  children: [
    {
      prefix: "a:b",
      count: 15,
      children: [
        { prefix: "a:b:c", count: 5 },
        {
          prefix: "a:b:d",
          count: 10
          children: [
            { prefix: "a:b:d:e", count = 7 },
            { prefix: "a:b:d:f", count = 3 }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    { prefix: "a:c", count: 5 }
  ]
}
```

Total number of leaves is huge (but I will pre-truncate them on server, I think, so that should not be a problem).

I can change output format as needed.

I need to make a web-UI to visualize this tree and be able to drill down to certain nodes, to let user to visually analyze which prefixes have largest weight (i.e. count).

I think that a [treemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) control should work here, but I'm open to other suggestions.

Please advise, which free JavaScript library I can reuse. Preferably something free, robust and easy to use (but non-free OK if it is excellent).

jQuery-aware libraries are preferable, but anything else is accepted if it is good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the [`JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit`](http://thejit.org/demos/) very interesting (haven't used it) but seems really promising *[open source]*

Comment: InfoVis' TreeMap is good, is very configurable, and works with data almost exactly in the format you provide.  One limitation is it requires the full data tree to render.  There is no built in means to dynamically load data on drill down.

Answer (score 1):

[ProtoVis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/) from the Stanford Visualization group is another option for you. See under the Hierarchies section in the example page.

Comment: Does it support drilling down the data? (I.e. when you click on treemap node, and view is zoomed to the subtree of that node.)

Comment: No, it doesn't. But it is flexible enough for you to easily bind an event handler to, say, `click` or `mouseover`. See http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/docs/interaction.html. And you may use jQuery UI's effect (e.g. transfer) to do the animation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/.

Comment: ProtoVis does not work very well on IE.  It contains a lot of JavaScript errors for most of its visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

If the hierarchy returned is not too deep, would a regular tree work? http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: No, sorry, regular trees are just not visual enough in this case. I need something more advanced like a treemap.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the treemap in [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org) to do a similar thing.

But instead of using the built-in drilling down and up function in the treemap from JIT, 
I found it easier to serve a single level of data to the treemap at a time, and then redraw it with new data when necessary.

Using that technique The JIT is fast, and easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

asked before in [Display JSON/YAML hierarchy as a tree in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244601/display-json-yaml-hierarchy-as-a-tree-in-html)

see the answer that display the tree in "divs".
it is possible to add a little javascript to the json property names, to show/hide the next div.

sorry, i don't have code ready, maybe i will, if asked nicely :)

Comment: Tree view would not work here — not visual enough. I'd like to find a treemap control or something else that would more effectively visualize weights of each node.